# Batch file to copy from remote desktop to local machine

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy

How do I copy a file from a remote desktop user's drive to my local machine using  `xcopy` or any other protocol?

My server path is `\\\Trail01` and the file location is: `C:\Users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop\Day2.R`

How can I use this is in my batch file?

I have tried this:

```
net use "\\\Trail01" "Trail01@1234" "/USER:ashique.sheikh"
XCOPY /Y \\\Trail01\c:\users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop\Day2.R  "D:\VMI"
```

But it doesn't work, it gives a path error.

How can I download this or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? And is it correct that you want to copy the file `day2.r` from `\\Trail01\c:\users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop\ ` to `D:\VMI`? It sounds wrong to have \\servername\c:\, so I think I've misunderstood something or there is something wrong with the actual path.

Comment: Yes i want to copy day.r from server to my local D drive.  when I take remote login I can see the file in c:\users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop\ of \\Trail01 so how can i download it from server directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, the access of drive c via network (`\\Trail01\c$`) is only allowed to administrators.

First of all you can check if you have the necessary rights to map the share `\\Trail01\c$` (explorer >> map network drive).

If this is not possible, maybe you can try to create a new share when you are in a remote session on the server. Right-Click on the folder which you need access (in your case `"c:\Users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop\Day2.R"`) 
in explorer >> properties >> sharing >> Advanced sharing.

If you could create a new share (which is called for example `specialshare`), please try to access via `\\Trail01\specialshare`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all - You can't write `\\Trail01\c:\`, so you should change it with `\\Trail01\c$\`

Try something like this...

```
XCOPY /Y "\\Trail01\c$\users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop\Day2.R" "D:\VMI"
```

Or perhaps this...

```
    PushD "\\Trail01\c$\users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop" &&(
XCOPY /Y Day2.R "D:\VMI"
    ) & PopD
```

Comment: It shows XCOPY /Y "\\Trail01\c$\users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop\Day2.R" "D:\VMI" Invalid drive specification and in PushD "\\Trail01\c$\users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop" &&(
XCOPY /Y Day2.R "D:\VMI"
    ) & PopD shows Access is denied. How can these show access is denied in this i used net use "\\Trial01" "Trial@1234" "/USER:ashique.sheikh"
PushD "\\Trial01\c$\users\ashique.sheikh\Desktop" &&(
XCOPY /Y Day2.R "D:\VMI"
    ) & PopD

Comment: What station is your server (Trail01) mapped to?

Comment: It is windows server 2012 R.                                                 Can i use putty or any other protocol in it?

Comment: I mean what station. As in your VMI folder is in a `D:\` station. What station is your Trail01 server? Since you've net used it, it should have a station.

Comment: It is just a remote server . I connect it with remote desktop connection by typing Trial01 only and it asked for username and password

Comment: I'd put `popd` in between the parentheses too, because if `pushd` fails, no `popd` should be done (think of nested `pushd`/`popd` pairs)...

Answer (score 0):

Command1: net use "\172.17.0.27" typePassword /user:domain\typeUsername
Command2: XCOPY /Y "\172.17.0.27\C$\Reports\hello.txt" "C:\Trades_Backup"

Command1 : It is going to access ip 172.17.0.27
Command2 : It is going to copy hello file from Reports folder of this ip to TradesBackup folder of your local system

Comment: Because other methods dint work well for me, but this worked. Might be useful for others reading post.